# Do I need to create client_id and client_secret for each user for implementing oauth?

Tags: javascript, api, oauth-2.0

here is my question :
I'm building an API which allows users to manage some objects at home via an application. 
I read along this article about grants for acquiring an access token, and the grant I should use : https://alexbilbie.com/guide-to-oauth-2-grants#which-oauth-20-grant-should-i-use

As far as I understood, as the application is a first party (we develop it), and the API are ours as well, it seems that I only need to ask them a login and a password (Implicit grant) for the oAuth flow authentication.

For now, the database contains users, and for each one a client_id and a client_secret. How should I manage passing those informations to the server though ?

Moreover, should each user have a client_id and a client_secret or should I manage to have unique ones for everyone that I could store in the application ?

Thanks

Comment: no client_id and client_secret are for each application that want to access to the resource.

Comment: Thanks could you post it as an answer please, as I accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No client_id and client_secret are for each application that want to access to the resource.